# how can Ifind specific text in excel and return with specific value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I find text in a cell and output should be a return value?

For example:

Find Apple in Cell `A1`, if true it will output "return value for apple"

If the search is false, it will always search the next row. If true it will stop.

Fruits: Apple, Banana, Cherry

Fruits

```
A1: 1 Apple
A2: 2 Banana
A3: 5 Cherry
```

Return Value

```
B1: Apple
B2: Banana
B3: Cherry
```

Search Fruits

```
D1: Banana
D2: Cherry
D3: Apple
```

Comment: Come on, what are you talking about?

Comment: Though your question is not very clear to me, probably you can do this using excel functions such as 
[Search](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495), [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), and some sort of [looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939537/how-to-loop-in-excel-without-vba-or-macros).  Another approach would be to use [Excel Marcos](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Create-a-macro-455512ef-3532-404e-b8dd-ea6589512c1b).

Answer (score -1):

User search formula: You need to put your query more clearly.

=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Apple",A1)>0,"Apple",""),"")

[image: Snapshot]