# how to do loops in excel without macro

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula

:/ sorry for restarting the question but unfortunately I don't got enough reps yet to comment on a post. [How to loop in excel without VBA or macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939537/how-to-loop-in-excel-without-vba-or-macros), so my question is practically identical but with a slightly different application. I've been wondering how I can make recursive(hope I'm using this fancy word right) loops in excel without macros.

for this particular example, it'd be more of a for loop, I want to make a vlookup for each character in a cell and then concatenate the result.

ideally, id be looking for something silly like 
=concatenate(array(for(A1,a,chars,vlookup(a,table,1,false))))

broken down into

=concatenate(array(for([target],[var],[attribute],vlookup([var],table,1,false))))

which would result in concatenate(vlookup(mid(A1,**1**,1),table,1,false),vlookup(mid(A1,**2**,1),table,1,false),vlookup(mid(A1,**3**,1),table,1,false). . . . for the character length of A1

I know what I wrote above looks retarded but that's why I'm asking the question; cause I really don't know. :P

if you're still confused as to why i want this, I currently have a sheet that turns text into code 128 barcodes using lookup tables, however, the references break every time I move it.

my current solution takes the input text, breaks each char into its own cell, apply the lookup, then recombine after a bit of math. I'm just wondering, the process is the same for each char,sooo shouldn't I be able to write it out in one neat and condensed equation using loops like i did above?

I know, i know, this process could be done with a macro but that's not my point. my question is can repetitive loops be written in excel as a formula?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.  This would also be significantly easier if you used multiple cells.  Depending on the results you're looking for there may be a formula-only solution to this, but right now the description seems like you just want to return the same combination of letters that already exists in A1 which doesn't make any sense because then your whole formula would just be `=A1`.  Please provide sample data and results to make your intentions more clear.

Comment: sure just for simplicity lets say in a lookup table a=1,b=2,c=3 and so forth, if you want a more meaningful lookup table for my application see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128 and scroll down to barcode widths. I'm using the Value column and the 128A column and learned how to do it with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HIEdwqnCG0&list=LL0ANW6vk32EuIjwX7W6zLfw&index=13&t=1639s

Comment: Do you have Excel 2016 or higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365 you can use this array formula:

```
=CONCAT(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IFERROR(MATCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),Sheet1!A:A,0),FALSE)*{1,1})))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This will return the values in Column B on Sheet 1 where each Letter in A1 is found in Column A on Sheet1.

For example my sheet1 looks like this:

[image]

So the formula on returns:

[image]

---

Now if the data in the table is sorted on the lookup column:

[image]

Then we can use this simpler array formula:

```
=CONCAT(LOOKUP(MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B))
```

[image]

---

Another variation, if the return is numbers then you can use SUMIF:

```
=CONCAT(SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),Sheet1!B:B))
```

---

As you can see the part that iterates through the word letter by letter is the:

```
MID(A1,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)
```

This part is what makes it an array formula and is available most versions of Excel.

The part that requires Office 365 is the CONCAT() wrapper.