# SUMIFS - reference multiple cells

Tags: excel, sum, sumifs

I work for a bookmaker and have the following problem.

I would like to find the sum of total stake for particular groups of clients for particular sports, between certain dates.

Here is the code i have at the moment which works well for 1 client `code` :

```
=SUMIFS(Databank!$G:$G,Databank!$C:$C,Template!$A$10,Databank!$J:$J,Template!$E24,Databank!B:B,">="&Template!$B$3,Databank!B:B,"<="&Template!$B$4)
```

Reference :

- Databank G is stake
- Databank C is client code
- Template A10 is the cell i'm referring to with a client code in
- Databank J is Sport
- Template E24 is the sport i would like summarising
- Databank B is date
- Template B3 and B4 are to and from dates.

Currently this formula tells me the total stake of the client in `A10` for the sport in `E24` between the dates in `B3` and `B4`.

I would like to amend the formula to be able to group more clients together from cells `A10` - `A100`, `A101` etc

Comment: Now, you got a summation for `A10`.  You want another one sum for `A11`, and another for `A12`, and so on.  don't you?

Comment: Hi, yes i get a summation for A10, i would like to include the client codes in A11, A12 etc into the figure.  So I end up with the total stake for X amount of clients in one cell

Comment: I would like to recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939537/how-to-loop-in-excel-without-vba-or-macros) solution. | Simply.. add another sheet, collect the result, retrieve it using ` = ` . (  :

Comment: @p._phidot_I have 22 different sports and a six groups of clients to make up, groups ranging from 3 people to 100 people.  I'm not sure if this solution will help

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of number crunching, you really should be using a PivotTable, and some Slicers to let you quickly and easily select the variables that you want the PivotTable to show the aggregated totals for.

See my answer at [VBA to copy data if multiple criteria are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211178/vba-to-copy-data-if-multiple-criteria-are-met/51214172#51214172) on how to insert a PivotTable. In your case, you need to drag the Stake field into the Values area of the PivotTable, and put the other fields into the Filters area.

Give Google a spin in regards to how to add slicers. Easy as pie.

Answer (score 0):

Find two empty columns, say `x` and `y`.

In `x10`, write

```
=SUMIFS(Databank!$G:$G
,Databank!$C:$C,Template!$A10
,Databank!$J:$J,Template!$E24
,Databank!B:B,">="&Template!$B$3
,Databank!B:B,"<="&Template!$B$4)
```

which replace `$A$10` of your formula with `$A10`.

Drag `x10` down to `x11`, `x12` and so on.

In `y1`, write `=SUM(X:X)` will return the summation.

Comment: Thank you, placed this on another sheet and it's working well